# How to visualize the segmented image region after ndimage.label and ndimage.find_objects?

Tags: computer-vision, scikit-image

I am currently trying to segment the image. I use ndimage.label to find the segmented features, and use ndimage.find_objects to generate tuple of slice to describe the features. However, I don't know how to visualize the segmented regions separately. Please let me know how to do that.

```
labeled_array, num_features = ndimage.label(image)
regions = ndimage.find_objects(labeled_array)
labeled_array=np.float32(labeled_array)
plt.imshow(labeled_array*.2, cmap='gray')
```

Before Segmented:

[image]

After Segmented:

[image]

Comment: You can get a binary mask by doing a comparison with any one single label, e.g.  `mask = (labeled_array == 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options in scikit-image for visualizing segmentations:

- [skimage.segmentation.mark_boundaries](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.segmentation.html#mark-boundaries) will draw lines (by default, yellow lines) around each labeled region in your image.
- [skimage.color.label2rgb](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.color.html#label2rgb) will make each region a different color (you pass in a list of colors as a parameter).
- As [Stéfan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214686/stefan-van-der-walt) suggested, you can visualize each region separately.

For the last option, try the following, after you have run the code above.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, num_features)
for i, (ax, region) in enumerate(zip(axes, regions)):
    ax.imshow((image == i+1)[region])
```